# How to change a production url in the Visual Studio

Tags: development

I projecting site local on Sharepoint Fundation. Now I would like to change the enviroment to the productive server. How change url to deploy Solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highlight the project in the solution explorer, in the properties window, change the Site Url to your production site.

Comment: I get its this error Error 1 Error occurred in deployment step 'Recycle IIS Application Pool': Cannot connect to the SharePoint site: http://tomy.qumak.pl:2222/. Make sure that this is a valid URL and the SharePoint site is running on the local computer. If you moved this project to a new computer or if the URL of the SharePoint site has changed since you created the project, update the Site URL property of the project.
  0 0 Add4

Comment: It is possible you do not have permissions to the site. Are you running VS as admin? If the server is not on your local machine you cannot deploy directly to it in Visual Studio 2010 (2012 you can).  Your option then is to package up the solution and deploy via powershell or in the UI on the remote server.